# JSP compilation error - Syntax error on token "throws", throw expected

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, taglib

We have a JSP application hosted in a Tomcat 7 server. As part of our build process, we have some automated tests running that call these JSP pages through HtmlUnit. 
We've noticed intermittent JSP compilation errors when some of the tests are attempting to access a JSP file. This does not seem to be linked to any particular test.

The last compilation error we've had for instance is:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: [1] in the generated java file: [/tmp/myproject/work/Tomcat/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp/admin/home_jsp.java]
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

An error occurred at line: [97] in the generated java file: [/tmp/myproject/work/Tomcat/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp/admin/home_jsp.java]
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

An error occurred at line: 1 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/jspf/taglibs.jspf
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
1: <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="authz" %>
2: <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
3: <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
4: <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>


An error occurred at line: 1 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/jspf/taglibs.jspf
Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
1: <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="authz" %>
2: <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
3: <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
4: <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>


An error occurred at line: 1 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/jspf/taglibs.jspf
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
1: <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="authz" %>
2: <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
3: <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
4: <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>


An error occurred at line: 1 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/jspf/taglibs.jspf
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
1: <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="authz" %>
2: <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
3: <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
4: <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>


An error occurred at line: 1 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/jspf/taglibs.jspf
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
1: <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="authz" %>
2: <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
3: <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
4: <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>


An error occurred at line: 1 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/jspf/taglibs.jspf
Syntax error on token "throws", throw expected
1: <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="authz" %>
2: <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
3: <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
4: <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>


An error occurred at line: 1 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/jsp/admin/home.jsp
Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
1: <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jspf/taglibs.jspf" %>
2: <html>
3: <head>
4:     <title>Administrator Home</title>
```

We do not see these errors neither in our local environments nor in any other environment than our environment in charge of running these system tests, and yes, we use the same code base.

These errors seem to happen only on the first access to the JSP file given that I can see in Tomcat jsp work directory that there is a home_jsp.java and a home_jsp.class, which means that the jsp file has been correctly translated into a servlet class and then correctly compiled later on. Also, I had a look at the home_jsp.java file and could not see any obvious error corresponding to the compilation error reported by the JSP compiler.

Any ideas / suggestions to help with this issue are appreciated.

Cheers,
Olivier

Answer (score 0):

We were not aware that we had 2 Tomcat instances actually using the same JSP work directory.

We have changed this so that each instance uses its own work folder and we haven't seen the issue again since.

This does not gives us the actual root cause but at least it has fixed our issue.